# Running code with a different version of Kryo with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kryo

I am trying to put together a Apache Spark Streaming application that will be consuming message from a message broker. I have everything worked out except for the fact that my messages are being serialized using `Kryo`.

Apache Spark is compiled with `Kryo` version 2.21, however my messages are serialized with version 2.24.0. When trying to deserialized I am getting a `NoSuchMethodError` because that method is not available in `Kryo` 2.21 (I am using `setCopyReferences(false)`).

Is there any easy way to overcome this problem? Do I need to recompile Spark on my own using the kryo version I need?